# DataGridView anchors

Tags: c#, datagridview, anchor, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Form with 2 DatagridViews placed side by side, but when I maximise the form they either remain with their original sizes or one overlaps another, depending on how I've set the anchors.
Is there a way I can limit how much those controls can grow to each direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Use `MaxiumSize.Width`, `MaxiumSize.Height` to set the maximum size of your control. You'll need to set minimum size as well using `MinimumSize.Width` and `MinimumSize.Height` properties.
[image]